# How to set different classpath in an unit test to load resource with Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-batch

I would like to create 2 test case with JUnit and Spring that requires both the same classpath resource *batch-configuration.properties* but content of this file differ depending on test.

Actually in my maven project, I create these file tree :

- *src/test/resources/test1/batch-configuration.properties*
- *src/test/resources/test2/batch-configuration.properties*

But how can I define my root classpath depending on my test case (files are loaded in `ExtractionBatchConfiguration` using `classpath:batch-configuration.properties`)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ExtractionBatchConfiguration.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:test1/batch-configuration.properties") // does not override ExtractionBatchConfiguration declaration
public class ExtractBatchTestCase {
    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        context = SpringApplication.run(ExtractionBatchConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {      
        jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(context.getBean(JobLauncher.class));
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(context.getBean(JobRepository.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGeneratedFiles() throws Exception {     
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(context.getBean("extractJob1", Job.class));
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        Assert.assertNotNull(jobExecution);
        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
        // ... other assert
    }

}
```

Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("batch-default-configuration.properties"),
    @PropertySource("batch-configuration.properties")
})
public class ExtractionBatchConfiguration { /* ... */ }
```

I am using Spring 4.0.9 (I cannot use 4.1.x) and JUnit 4.11

*EDIT:*

After using custom ApplicationContextInitializer suggested by hzpz to override my properties locations (application.properties + batch-configuration.properties) that solve some problems, I am experiencing another problem with @ConfigurationProperties :

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ldap.contextsource"/*, locations = "application.properties"*/) 
public class LdapSourceProperties { 
    String url;
    String userDn;
    String password;
    /* getters, setters */
}
```

and configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LdapSourceProperties.class)
public class LdapConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ContextSource contextSource(LdapSourceProperties properties) {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(properties.getUrl());
        contextSource.setUserDn(properties.getUserDn());
        contextSource.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
        return contextSource;
    }
}
```

All LdapSourceProperties's field are null when ContextSource is created but if I uncomment `locations = "application.properties"` it's only works if application.properties is in the root classpath. The default environment used by @ConfigurationProperties seems doesn't contains neested properties...

*Alternative solution :*

Finally I put all my properties into `application-<profile>.properties` files (and remove @PropertySource definition). I can now use `application-test1.properties` and `application-test2.properties`. On my test class, I can set `@ActiveProfiles("test1")` to activate a profile and load associated properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand how JUnit tests with Spring work. The purpose of `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is to create the `ApplicationContext` for you (using `@ContextConfiguration`). You do not need to create the context yourself.

If the context is properly set up, you may then use `@Autowired` to get the dependencies you need in your test. `ExtractBatchTestCase` should look something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ExtractionBatchConfiguration.class })
public class ExtractBatchTestCase {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("extractJob1")
    private Job job;

    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {      
        jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGeneratedFiles() throws Exception {     
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        Assert.assertNotNull(jobExecution);
        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
        // ... other assert
    }

}
```

Second, the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) for `@ProperySource` states:

> In cases where a given property key exists in more than one .properties file, the last `@PropertySource` annotation processed will 'win' and override. [...]
>
> In certain situations, it may not be possible or practical to tightly control property source ordering when using `@ProperySource` annotations. For example, if the `@Configuration` classes [...] were registered via component-scanning, the ordering is difficult to predict. In such cases - and if overriding is important - it is recommended that the user fall back to using the programmatic PropertySource API.

Create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` for your tests to add some test properties with highest search priority that will always 'win':

```
public class MockApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
        MockPropertySource mockEnvVars = new MockPropertySource().withProperty("foo", "bar");
        propertySources.addFirst(mockEnvVars);
    }
}
```

Declare it using `@ContextConfiguration`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ExtractionBatchConfiguration.class }, 
                      initializers = MockApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class ExtractBatchTestCase {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Good idea but doesn't works : *.ExtractionBatchConfiguration; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [batch-configuration.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist* with this ApplicationContextInitializer#initialize : `applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:test1/batch-configuration.properties"));`

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your code: you posted `ResourcePropertySource("classpath:test1/batch-configuration.properties")` but the error message states `class path resource [batch-configuration.properties]` (without `test1`). I just verified that the code works. Please check your code and try again.

Comment: This code error may come from `ExtractionBatchConfiguration` class where `@PropertySource("batch-configuration.properties")` is defined without any prefix... But I have an idea, I forget to mention that I am using Spring Boot ! And I get ApplicationContext by using `context = SpringApplication.run(ExtractionBatchConfiguration.class)` so I think that my `@ContextConfiguration` definition is ignored... I am actually reading Spring Boot unit testing section to find a better option (because I am also using Spring Batch...).

Comment: Well, the original `batch-configuration.properties` needs to exist, too. The idea is that properties defined there are overriden with the properties from `test1/batch-configuration.properties`. What are you doing with `context`? `@ContextConfiguration` should work just fine, but you may try `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead.

Comment: I just add some code in my test case with Spring Boot and Spring Batch to show how I use `context`. `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` run immediately batch application without any control in job execution. I want to select which job must be executed and also get the job execution status. How can I perform that with @SpringApplicationConfiguration ?

Comment: First of all you need to understand how JUnit tests with Spring work. I updated my answer and hope it helps.

Comment: Ok but with this configuration `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ExtractionBatchConfiguration.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)` doesn't works because Spring Boot autoconfiguration doesn't configure automatically beans (like datasource or others...) but I solve the problem using spring boot context loader : `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ExtractionBatchConfiguration.class }, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)` and I can now use autowired well configured beans.

Comment: Using custom ApplicationContextInitializer avoid some problems but I am now experiencing problem with `@ConfigurationProperties` spring boot annotation. Could you see my edit ?

Comment: Finally I put all my properties into `application-<profile>.properties`. I can now use `application-test1.properties` and `application-test2.properties`. On my test class, I can set `@ActiveProfiles("test1")` to activate a profile and load associated properties. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good idea! Glad I could help.